# Django INSTALLED_APPS can't get apps with underscores right - why?

Tags: django

I've got a Django project, in there two apps, let's say ***cheese*** and ***mouse_and_cat***. While adding both to INSTALLED_APPS, I first wrote there

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'cheese.apps.CheeseConfig',
    'mouse_and_cat.apps.Mouse_and_catConfig',
]
```

but it resulted only in error that "*mouse_and_cat.app is not a package*". I tried to change it to **'mouse_and_cat.apps.MouseandcatConfig'**, but it didn't help - somehow I thought that would be the case. I searched in Google and kept the first "cheese line", but changed second to only `'mouse_and_cat'` - and it works now. But... what's the case with underscores, why does Django act so weird, when an app is named this way? Is there something I'm missing here? Now I know underscores aren't preferred naming pattern and so I will avoid it, but it still bothers me, because I believe this error was somehow more my fault than Django's.

Comment: What is in the `Mouse_and_catConfig` package/file?

Comment: actually, both cheese and mouse_and_cat are "clean", I mean they were both made few minutes ago. actually x2, I've made ~5 new apps, and 2 of them had underscores - and Django couldn't get right only those ones.

Comment: Is there an `app.py` in the `mouse_and_cat` folder/app?

Comment: Yes, it is. So I guess the most important thing is, how the class is named there - and it's MouseAndCatConfig. It makes sense now, I guess

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't do anything with ***underscore***, It should be the ***dotted path*** to the **app configuration `class`**. This configuration class usually found in **`/app_name/apps.py`** file, here the app_name is **`mouse_and_cat`**.
If you want to get it to work, you could either put the app_name (**`mouse_and_cat`**) or the ***dotted path to the class*** in the **`INSTALLED_APPS`** list.

Comment: I don't get it. Why does Django have no problems with cheese.apps.CheeseConfig, while doing the same with underscored names **is** a problem?

Comment: Here the **`CheeseConfig`** is a class name and `Mouse_and_catConfig` maynot. Can you add your `/mouse_and_cat/apps.py` file to the question?

Answer (score 1):

From Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#configuring-applications

I tried creating my own AppConfig subclass as it explains on the link above and it worked for me.

At `mouse_and_cat/apps.py`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class Mouse_and_Cat_Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'mouse_and_cat' # app_name to be configured
```

At `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'mouse_and_cat.apps.Mouse_and_Cat_Config',
    ...
]
```